# Find angle from triangle in python (Similar to using sin-1 on scientific calculators)?

Tags: python, math, geometry, trigonometry, angle

I want to find the angle from a triangle in Python. I searched other topics here but none of them helped me...

My code:

```
from math import hypot, sin

opposite = 5
adjacent = 8.66
hypotenuse= hypot(opposite, adjacent)

# Trigonometry - Find angle
sine = opposite / hypotenuse
print(sin(sine))
```

So, i have a calculator here that have the Sin-1 function, and when i use it in "sine" calc, it returns me the angle 30.

The problem is, i am not finding this sin-1 function on Python. Can someone help me?

Output:

```
# Whatever this is
0.47943519230195053
```

Expected output (Which my calculator gives me):

```
# Angle
30
```

Comment: "The problem is, i am not finding this sin-1 function on Python. Can someone help me?" Did you try putting `python sin-1` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+sin-1)? How about [`python inverse sine`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+inverse+sine)? Did you try [looking through the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/math.html) for the `math` standard library module

Comment: Yes, as i said on the first part, i searched on other topics but i couldnt understand none of them.

Comment: Okay, so when you looked at the documentation, did you see the part where it says "
math.asin(x) Return the arc sine of x, in radians. The result is between -pi/2 and pi/2." If you saw this, why did it not answer the question? How about reading the linked duplicate? When I try the `python inverse sine` search, the summary of the first link (without even having to visit the page) tells me "The asin () function of the Math library is also used for calculating the inverse sine value (between -1 to 1) of a given input value in Python". So what was the remaining problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get angle, you need `arcsin` function (`sin-1`), in Python it is `math.asin`. Also note that result is in radians, perhaps you want to show degrees:

```
from math import hypot, asin, degrees

opposite = 5
adjacent = 8.66
hypotenuse= hypot(opposite, adjacent)

# Trigonometry - Find angle
sine = opposite / hypotenuse
rad_angle = asin(sine)
deg_angle = degrees(rad_angle)
print(rad_angle, deg_angle)

>>>0.5236114777699694 30.000727780827372
```

Also note that having two catheti, you can get angle using `atan` function (inverse tangent) without hypotenuse calculation

```
print(degrees(atan(opposite/ adjacent)))
```

or `atan2` - takes two arguments, returns result in the full circle range (not important for triangles, but might help in vector calculations)

```
print(degrees(atan2(opposite, adjacent)))
```

Comment: I prefer `atan2(opposite, adjacent)`.